# Shell script - date/time and list of users

Tags: linux, shell, date, time

I need to write shell script with while loop, so I did that, but next problem is shell script need to make new file with list of users, and date and time of calling that script.

Comment: Please add your current code to the question. Show what you have tried so far, so others can help you.

Answer (score 0):

An example for your quick start. This one's POSIX compatible as I prefer `$()` over backticks.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$(date -u '+[%F %T]') Users: $(users)"
```

Output:

```
[2014-08-06 17:30:21] Users: user1 user2 user3 user4
```

Comment: Need to use character " > " to forward those users in one file.